# Coefficients of members in a base-point free linear system

Tags: algebraic-geometry, birational-geometry

Let $\mathbb{K}\in \{\mathbb{Z},\mathbb{Q},\mathbb{R}\}$ and let $D$ be a base-point free(or ample if it is necessary) $\mathbb{K}$-divisor on a normal projective variety.

I have two questions:

1. When $\mathbb{K}=\mathbb{Q}$ or $\mathbb{R}$, can we always take $D^\prime\in |D|_{\mathbb{K}}$ such that $D^\prime$ has arbitary small coefficients?
2. When $\mathbb{K}=\mathbb{Z}$ or $\mathbb{Q}$, is there an $E\in |D|_{\mathbb{K}}$ such that $E$ is a prime divisor?

Comment: Regarding your first question, what if you let $D$ be a line in $\mathbb P^2$? Every divisor in its complete linear system is a line with coefficient $1$. Unless I'm misunderstanding the question perhaps?

Comment: @TabesBridges When $\mathbb{K}=\mathbb{R}$, the complete linear system in the question is an $\mathbb{R}$-complete linear system, i.e. one needs to consider every effective $\mathbb{R}$-divisor such that it is $\mathbb{R}$-linearly equivalent to $D$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(1) is fully true (as long as we're over an infinite field). Indeed, for any $n$, since $|D|$ is free we can pick $E_1, ... , E_n \in |D|$ distinct and consider $F_n = 1/n\sum E_i$. The coefficients of $F_n$ get arbitrarily small as $n$ gets large and each $F_n$ is $\mathbb{Q}$-linearly equivalent to $D$.

(2) is true in dimensions $\geq 2$ and characteristic $0$ by Bertini's theorem. For a counterexample in the case of curves take $X = \mathbb{P}^1$ and the complete linear series $|\mathcal{O}(2)|$. If $D$ is a $\mathbb{K}$-divisor which is $\mathbb{K}$-linearly equivalent to a divisor in this linear series, we would have that the degree of $D$ is 2, so it cannot be a prime divisor.

Apologies for the substantial edit. I didn't read the word 'free' initially and the old answer was incorrect.

Comment: Hi @Daniel, the choice of $E_i$ are distinct, but they may share common component correct? how can you guarantee that $F_n = 1/n\sum E_i
$ has coefficients goes to zero if they have share same components, do you apply Bertini theorem here or other reason?

Comment: @yili You're right; I should have insisted that these distinct divisors are irreducible, and for this, we need to use some Bertini theorem for irreducibility.

Comment: got it thank you Daniel.